# Using 2 @model in View - ASP.Net MVC Bootstrap

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, model, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a View that gets the model directly from a database table. I use the `@model IEnumerable<TestMVC.USR_MSTR>` to display data in `<table>`. Right now, I'm trying to implement table pagination I've read from a tutorial (`@model PagedList.IPagedList<CDS.USR_GRP_MSTR>`). It uses the same model with different type, so right now I'm having problems how to attach the same model with different type in my View.

I've read that I should create a `ViewModel` that calls the models I need but I'm quite new to MVC and still get confused in some areas. I've created a UserViewModel for that but not sure if I implemented it correctly, because in my View I cannot get the columns of my USR_MSTR model so I revereted back to my posted code below.

View (Index.cshtml)

```
@model IEnumerable<TestMVC.USR_MSTR>
@*@model PagedList.IPagedList<CDS.USR_GRP_MSTR>*@
@using PagedList.Mvc;

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "User", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="container">
        @Html.DropDownList("UserFilter")
        <table id="dbTable" onclick="gettabledata('dbTable','dbBody','0')" class="table table-scroll table-condensed table-hover table-striped bootgrid-table" aria-busy="false">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="hidden">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.USR_ID)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Users", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.UserSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
                        @*This is to create a link that sorts the Users in descending*@
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="dbBody">
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="hidden">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.USR_ID)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.USR_DESC)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
}
```

Controller (UserController.cs)

```
using TestMVC.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using PagedList;

namespace MVCTest.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
    MVCTestEntities _db = new MVCTestEntities();

        // GET: User
        public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
        {
            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.UserSort = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
            ViewBag.DateSort = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

            if (searchString != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }

            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

            var users = from u in _db.USR_MSTR
                            select u;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                users = users.Where(s => s.USR_DESC.Contains(searchString));
            }

            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "name_desc":
                    users = users.OrderByDescending(ug => u.USR_DESC);
                    break;
                case "Date":
                    users = users.OrderBy(ug => u.CREA_DT);
                    break;
                case "date_desc":
                    users = users.OrderByDescending(ug => u.CREA_DT);
                    break;
                default:
                    users = users.OrderBy(ug => u.USR_DESC);
                    break;
            }

            int pageSize = 10;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

            var filters = GetUserGroupFilter();
            ViewBag.UserGroupFilter = GetSelectListItems(filters);

            return View(users.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }
    }
}
```

ModelView (UserViewModel.cs)
- This is where I get confused, did I implemented it correctly? I just get the 2 @models in my view and put it here so that this is the only one my view should call

```
namespace TestMVC.ViewModels
{
    public class UserViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<CDS.USR_MSTR> table { get; set; }
        public PagedList.IPagedList<CDS.USR_MSTR> pagination { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think you need a view model with `IEnumerable<USR_MSTR>` and `IPagedList<USR_MSTR>` (`IPagedList` is `IEnumerable`)?

Comment: What you should have is a view model which contains properties `string Filter` and `IPagedList<USR_MSTR>` so that you can bind you dropdown to the property (and it will be selected when you return the view (and currently you dropdownlist will throw an exception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the `PagedList` as your `Model`, you do not have to pass the original `IEnumerable`. Just pass the paged list as your model.

```
@model IPagedList<CDS.USR_MSTR>
```

Then in your view code, just use it like `IEnumerable`:

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
```

Comment: Thanks dude! But in my table headers, I'm having errors in this code: `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.USR_ID)`. It says "IPagedList<USR_MSTR> does not contain a definition for USR_ID and no extension method USR_ID accepting a first argument of type IPagedList<USR_MSTR> could be found"

Comment: Try: `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.FirstOrDefault().USR_ID`

Comment: I *think* this works even if the list is empty because it only parses the expression, it doesn't execute it. I am checking that now.

Comment: Ok, I verified that it DID work even with an empty list.

Comment: It worked! Thans man! :D However, I'll still look into implementing a View with 2 different Model, I might encounter that sooner or later. Thanks again!